# Extracting data from a column to another one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have thousands of data on a column that is similar to

```
1651651465,"15654"
41654544,"4814"
```

they are all in a single column (like A1, A2, A3,....)

I want to save the number before `,` to A1(A2,A3,A4...) and the number inside `""` to B1 (B2,3,...). how can I do it?

then it will be like:

```
       A            B
1   1651651465    15654
2   41654544       4814
3   etc
4   etc
```

If you know how to do it in open office, I can use open office then save it as MS excel.

Comment: can you specify which version of Office are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the column.
Go to **Data** tab and select **Text to Columns**.
Select **delimited** on the first page , click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
Select **comma** in the next page , click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub reformit()
    Dim s As String, N As Long, L As Long
    s = Chr(34)
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For L = 1 To N
        v = Replace(Cells(L, "A"), s, "")
        ary = Split(v, ",")
        Cells(L, "A") = ary(0)
        Cells(L, "B") = ary(1)
    Next L
End Sub
```